# PHP Session Random Data

Tags: php, mysql, session

We have an application that works perfectly in LOCALHOST but when we transfer the code to the server there is a problem with PHP sessions.

As some people suggested we changed the session handler to DB since we use we two load-balanced servers.

The problem is that when you refresh a page Data column in session table changes randomly from some encoded chars to a serialized array. Like:

```
HbkEC0ZTvozN-e4pxjReRPmEI3Pd8cNB1QdNImNjWuVeGaGzaj...
```

to:

```
cookiename|s:32:"0b0801a1e9c0e30d2bc3c329b16afa00"...
```

!!!

This accrues completely random for example you refresh the page for 4 times and you have the same data but in 5th refresh data changes.

any suggestion?

Comment: give us a little insight. So a loadbalancer with 2 machines behind it. MySQL in master-master?

Comment: Two fronted servers with one DRBD cluster for database with one active node.

Comment: Can you post sources of DB Session handler? And check that these are realy same on both nodes...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have different server configuration. Try to check

```
session.serialize_handler
```

settings in your `php.ini`

Comment: Both have the same value.

Comment: PHP setting are the same except in one of them we have "zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so"